# How to pass values to javascript event handling method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling

I have this thing, I need to pass two values to a method written in javascript and it's handling the onClientClick event of a button, how can I do that?

**Edit**

I'm using a radbutton from telerik and there's no button.add.attributes !!

**Edit2**
The values I need to pass are server-side values.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and tell us where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead:

```
(function(){
 var parameter1, parameter2;
 button.onclick = function() { //you have access to both variables parameter1,parameter2
                               //and doesn't interfere with the event object passed 
                             };
})();
```

or

```
function returnEventHandler(param1,param2)
{
 return function(){
 // your event handler code, play around with parameters, example
  return param1 + param2;
 };
}

button.onclick = returnEventHandler("one","two");
```

Comment: @Shaza yes, they make use of closures, the ability of inner functions to have access to the scope object of the function they were defined in, even after that function has finished executing. Pretty much, a core javascript technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it straight-up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo(parm1, parm2)
{
    // Click event logic goes in here
}
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn1" text="Do Foo" onclientClick="foo(23,'foooing')" />
```

**Edit**

It is worth mentioning that the 'onClientClick' and 'onClick' methods for an ASP Button object are distinct in every way.

It is like having two separate functions running on click, one which will execute on the client side using javascript and another which will fire a reload or Post-Back and execute on the server.

One important point here is that the client side code will always run first and it is possible to stop the server side code from executing if you so desire.

Comment: Won't this erase the event object? that normally is the first parameter of an event handler?

Comment: @Ellu: yes it will, but I am presuming for the client side script he does not need the event object. And if there is an additional Server side click function, it will still receive the event object without interruption.

Comment: I can't pass constants, I need to pass variable values to the javascript method